# Windows 10: add group from Azure AD to Remote Desktop Users group

Tags: windows, azure, powershell, windows-10, azure-active-directory

I am able to add user from AAD to "Remote Desktop Users group" like this:

```
net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" /add "AzureAD\john.doe@example.com"
```

How to do it for a group?
I tried:

```
net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" /add "AzureAD\my-group"
```

but it is not working, altough my-group is actually exist in AAD.

I am not using AD, just AAD. I am not even AD admin.

Windows is joined to AAD like this:
http://anoopcnair.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Windows-10-RTM-Azure-AD-Join-1.png

Thanks

Comment: Is the user part of the AD domain (not AAD) which you were able to add to Remote Desktop users group as Net localgroup is used to add local or domain users to the groups ?